# Is it okay to screw self-tapping screws into a steel lintel of unknown thickness?

Tags: screws, steel, blinds

I want to install blinds into windows that have a metal lintel. The lintel appears to be a steel beam of unknown thickness. Can I just screw self-tapping screws in there? Should I drill a pilot hole first?

Comment: You're going to have a very difficult time driving a tap into a flat plate of metal _without_ having first drilled a pilot hole. **Here's an alternate thought**: Mount the blinds to the side of the window frame instead of the top. I've installed a fair number of blinds, and to my recollection, every single one has had mounts that could be installed either way.

Comment: Yeah, self-tapping (self-drilling) screws are generally intended for sheet metal, or fairly light steel structures such as roof trusses. The pilot tip needs to be able to pop through before the threads are involved, and they simply won't go in if there's too much thickness. The threads will just strip.

Comment: Self-tapping or self-drilling? Big difference. Self-tapping (needle or notch tip) won't touch beam steel. They'll only do sheet metal.

Comment: Freeman has a good suggestion but if you're intent on using the top mount buy a tap and drill set. You can get them in most common sizes for less than $10. Comes with the tap for tapping the threads and the correct size drill bit.

Comment: use supermagnets ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=supermagnet+hook&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: @FreeMan - side fastenings are far more dependant on the accuracy of your measuring ;) top-fix can be a whole lot more cavalier. I'd use self-drillers, but you're going to need some grunt balanced with finesse to get into an RSJ without the torque just smashing the fitting as it pulls tight. I'd pilot it. Safer if you're not used to that kind of work.

Comment: TBH, @Tetsujin, I've always done the top mount, so I can't speak to the accuracy required, but it seems to me that they both need to have the brackets fairly accurately placed in order for the blinds to hang correctly. I'll take your word for it, though...

Comment: @FreeMan - It's merely that, if you buy off-the shelf blinds, you can either buy larger & trim to fit, or just get the next size down. I've seen it done sooooo many times it hurts ;) 2" gap either side, but they cover the glass, so it's "good enough". Can't fasten those to the inner faces, got to be top fix.

Comment: Ahhh... _that_ kind of accuracy. Gotcha!

Comment: @FreeMan yep, unfortunately as others have said I can't to a side mount. Not only are there spacing issues but the brackets themselves wont allow it.